# SQL Debugging Help Needed

Tags: amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, cross-join

I am writing a query in Redshift to answer the question "Give the average lifetime spend of users who spent more on their first order than their second order." This is based off of an order_items table which has one row for every item ordered (so an order with 3 items would be represented in 3 rows). Here's a snapshot of the first 10 rows:

First 10 rows of `order_items`:

[image: first 10 rows of order_items]

Here is my solution:

```
with 
  cte1_lifetime as (
      select oi.user_id, sum(oi.sale_price) as lifetime_spend
      from order_items as oi
      group by oi.user_id
  ),
  
  cte2_order as (
      select oi.user_id, oi.order_id, sum(oi.sale_price) as order_total, rank() over(partition by oi.user_id order by oi.created_at) as order_rank
      from order_items as oi
      group by oi.user_id, oi.order_id, oi.created_at
      order by oi.user_id, oi.order_id
  ),
  
  cte3_first_order as (
      select user_id, order_id, order_total
      from cte2_order
      where order_rank=1
      order by user_id, order_id
  ),
  
  cte4_second_order as (
      select user_id, order_id, order_total
      from cte2_order
      where order_rank=2
      order by user_id, order_id
  )
  
  
select avg(cte1.lifetime_spend) as average_lifetime_spend
from cte1_lifetime as cte1
where exists (
      select *
      from cte3_first_order as cte3, cte4_second_order as cte4
      where cte3.user_id=cte4.user_id
      and cte1.user_id=cte3.user_id
      and cte3.order_total > cte4.order_total)
```

And here is the answer key:

```
WITH
  table1 AS
    (SELECT user_id, order_id,
    SUM(sale_price) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as order_total,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) AS "sequence"
    FROM order_items)
    ,

  table2 AS
    (SELECT user_id, SUM(sale_price) AS lifetime_spend
    FROM order_items
    WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT t1.user_id
        FROM table1 t1, table1 t2
        WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.sequence = 1 AND t2.sequence = 2 AND t1.order_total>t2.order_total
          AND t1.user_id = order_items.user_id)
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1)

SELECT AVG(lifetime_spend)
FROM table2
```

These answers yield slightly different results on the same data- an average lifetime spend of $215 vs $220. I'd really like to understand why they are different but so far I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any sample data that demonstrate the differences you are seeing?  Looking over the code I can see several places where things can diverge. But knowing which, if any, are causing your difference is not knowable without some data.

Comment: @BillWeiner yes I have some sample data, but I am new to stack. What's the best way for me to share it with you?

Comment: The best way, if the data is small enough, is to just add the DDL and INSERTs to your question.  Does the data in the "first 10 rows of order_items" show the issue you are seeing or is more / specific data needed?